# can you concatenate column index number

Tags: excel

I'm trying to add more than one Col_index_num to a vlookup.  Is it even possible?

```
=VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,CONCATENATE(4,5),FALSE)
```

Comment: Can you please share an example scenario of what is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write it the other way round i.e.

`=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,4,FALSE),VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,5,FALSE))`

Edit (you can add other custom formatting as required):

`=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,4,FALSE),", ",VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,5,FALSE))`

Comment: can I add some formatting and spacing like I would for a standard concat? such as `=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,4,FALSE)" &, & ",VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,5,FALSE))`

Comment: `=CONCATENATE(VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,4,FALSE)" &, & "VLOOKUP(CustomerList!A1,Customers,5,FALSE))`